# For Loop to populate Array?

Tags: android, loops

In the ImageAdapter class of this tutorial, http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

I would like to create and populate an array using a for loop. But it seems no matter where I place it, it causes an error.

For example, under `private Context mContext;` I put in the following and it causes an error. I think the loop is good, I'm just not sure where I can put it.

`private String[] myString;
for (int number = 0; number <= 12; number++) {
    myString[number] = "image" + number;
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create and populate the array in the constructor. Don't forget to actually instantiate the array before you start populating it.

```
public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
    myString = new String[12]; //create array
    for (int number = 0; number < myString.length; number++) { 
        myString[number] = "image" + number; 
    }
}
```

You should perhaps work on your Java a bit before jumping straight into Android.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
String[] myString = new String[12];
for (int number = 0; number <= 12; number++) {
  myString[number] = "image" + number;
}
```

Comment: This won't help if he's just going to paste it outside of any method or constructor :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public ImageAdapter(Context c)
 {
    mContext = c;

    myString = new String[12]; //create array


   for (int number = 0; number < myString.length; number++) { 

        myString[number] = "image" + number; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give at least a small explanation of your code. Thanks